# SQL query to combine 2 columns possible?

Tags: sql, db2-400

This query is not what we need. the 2 ENT# need to be IHGRC# if = adent# + adsfx. that is how they store in the app. Can that be combined that way? For example 
HRGRC# = 2558807001

adent# = 2558807
adsfx# = 001

this would be a match.

```
SELECT OEINH2.IHDOCD, OEINH2.IHINV#, OEINH2.IHGRC#, ADRES1.ADINTA, ADRES1.ADENT#, ADRES1.ADSFX#
 FROM   ASTDTA.OEINH2 
        INNER JOIN ASTDTA.ADRES1 ON OEINH2.IHENT#=ADRES1.ADENT#

 ORDER BY OEINH2.IHINV#
```

Comment: Huh?  Sample data and desired results would really help other people understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Without the DDL, the proposed [and accepted] concatenation of what are apparently numeric values, esp. when coded without explicit casting, can be a very flawed technique. Notably, conspicuously seems one should infer from the OP that the desire\expectation is that the following expression and literal value should be treated as equivalent, however the following logical predicate yeilds **false**: `(2558807 concat 001) = 2558807001`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to concatenate the values, you can use `concat()`:

```
select concat(adent#, adsfx) as HRGRC#
```

or use the concatenation operator:

```
select(adent# || adsfx) as HRGRC#
```